# How to make Generic Integration between two services

Tags: javascript, c#, api, generics, integration

Context :

Existing integration:

[image: Existing Integration]

Generic integration:

[image: Generic Integration]

1. Each Accounting ERP have different requirement for example ERP accounting 1 support sending a PDF to their system, ERP accounting 2 only support a Memo
2. Mostly each Accounting has the same mapping data, but have a different value on API response for example on ERP accounting 1 order named "orderpp" , on ERP accounting 2 order named "orderss"
3. WorkOrder Company make Integration between their services and ERP accounting company, for example in WorkOrder company, they make a workorder based on Order/Quotation on Accounting
4. Integration use C# and Javascript language
5. Handshake method use API Key, OAuth2 or Webhooks

My Question

1. How to make a generic integration that can adapt with the other Integration or can adjust with the new one?
2. it is possible that one Integration can fit with many Integration?

My Idea

1. Make an application can will generate Integration like this
   [Generic Integration Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9JaP.png)

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: As a general reply: you need to make an abstraction layer that means higher level code doesn't have to care about things like whether it needs to be a PDF or a "Memo", the name of the orders, etc. You should create your own objects to represent these things and the abstraction layer will convert between your objects and the service's objects. This will potentially impose limitations on what you can do as you'll be stuck with the lowest common denominator.

Comment: So it means, first, I need to map what services will have Integration, for example, Work order -> Invoice?
And what do you mean by "lowest common denominator"? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I mean you need a common way of representing what you need to send from your service to ERP Accounting 1, ERP Accounting 2, and ERP Accounting 3. Then the individual implementation for each accounting service will take your object, convert it to the specific one for the service, and send it (etc.). By lowest common denominator, I mean that if one service supports something extra that the other ones don't, then it might not be easy (or possible) to make that available through the abstraction, meaning you might only have the features common between them.

Comment: So it will be more tricky if I added a specific one that only supports one ERP accounting, right?
if it possible to have  generic integration that has like on/off switch?, lets say that will be a button that supports generating custom requirement for the Integration

Comment: You could work around it with interfaces and careful design. So if one supports some special feature, you could consider what that means in a more general sense (e.g. if another service also had a very similar feature) and then add like `IMySpecialFeature` to the service. Then you could actually check if the service you're working with has it.

Comment: Oke, I got your point about the high level! thanks,
but for technical perspective, it is possible for the custom button? in my understanding, in the back-end part of that button, it will be "If else" algoritm for checking every or else?

Comment: It's certainly possible. You could conditionally display it (does the abstraction indicate this service is available?), etc.